Angular APP_INITIALIZER not called
My APP_INITIALIZER seems to fail the Observable test in the Angular framework code and is never called. I have an appInitFactory, and a service class containing the init logic. The app module correctly configged, and the init method returns the Observable. I've looked at other posts, which led to this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-goyhqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finit.service.ts but it didn't work for me. My code below. Thanks for any comments
app_module
export function initializeAppFactory(uscfg: UserConfigService): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => uscfg.loadUserInfo();
};
...
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
           useFactory: () => initializeAppFactory, 
           multi: true, 
           deps: [UserConfigService]}

service method

 public loadUserInfo(): Observable<any> {
   let obs: Observable<any> = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/auth-info',  httpOptions)
     .pipe(tap(value => {
     ... process, incl more asynch calls; the Obs is not subscribed
   }));
   return obs;
 }

Angular code, iterating over and running the initializers. The return seems to be the initializer function, not the observable. The test in isSubscribable is "not null obj and obj has subscribe function" which fails.
/** @internal */
  runInitializers() {
    if (this.initialized) {
      return;
    }

    const asyncInitPromises = [];
    for (const appInits of this.appInits) {
      const initResult = appInits();
      if (isPromise(initResult)) {
        asyncInitPromises.push(initResult);
      } else if (isSubscribable(initResult)) {
        const observableAsPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
          initResult.subscribe({complete: resolve, error: reject});
        });
        asyncInitPromises.push(observableAsPromise);
      }
    }

/**
 * Determine if the argument is a Subscribable
 */
export function isSubscribable<T>(obj: any|Subscribable<T>): obj is Subscribable<T> {
  return !!obj && typeof obj.subscribe === 'function';
}


Your code should work. Can you look into providing a non-working stackblitz repro ?

I've not used StackBlitz but I'll look at it. Can you shed any light on the Angular behavior? The framework iterates over the initializers, calling each, getting the return, and tests the return as Promise, then as Observable. But it is apparently testing my init function, not the return value.

APP_INITILIAZER pushes to a promise array to do a Promise.all to await also async initializer. The observable is only converted to an promise here.

Yes, but the result of the execution of my function is not recognized as an Observable, in the above loop. Rather the function itself seems to be tested for Observable (presence of subscribe). I enter the isSubscribable function under debug, but execute the false code upon return

This is why I'm asking for a repro. What you shared with us should work.

I made a stackblitz example, but could not reproduce the problem. I downloaded the example to my env, ran correctly there, with same version of Angular, TS as my project code. The obj passed to isSubscribable is different, has subscribe, passes the test.
link

I've compared the 2 apps under debug and the code for the correct app is quite different, goes thru an injection phase, apparently, that injects the initializer, which returns Obs when called. My app does not inject anything, and returns my init function itself when called. The code is packaged differently in the 2 cases. Looking at both cases on my machine. The reason is presumably something in the config, still wondering.

You shouldn't wrap "initializeAppFactory" inside another arrow function.
export function initializeAppFactory(uscfg: UserConfigService): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => uscfg.loadUserInfo();
};
...
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
           useFactory: initializeAppFactory, // No wrapping in arrow function
           multi: true, 
           deps: [UserConfigService]}


That's how Angular doc writes it
function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<any> {   return () => httpClient.get("https://someUrl.com/api/user")     .pipe(tap(user => { ... })

so your initializeAppFactory returns a function that returns an observable. SO you shouldn't wrap it again like this: useFactory: () => initializeAppFactory. You should just do  useFactory: initializeAppFactory like in the docs at standalone component section: https://v17.angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER.

You were referring to the factory configuration, not the factory declaration. You are correct, configging the factory directly, not as function, works.
`// configuration
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeAppFactory, multi: true, deps: [UserConfigService]}
// declaration of factory
export function initializeAppFactory(uscfg: UserConfigService) {
// declaration of init method
loadUserInfo() { `
